# React-native core.js Promise polyfill does not seem to report unhandledRejection of Promises

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-native

I can't seem to trace the reason why React-Native (0.13.2) does not report ES6 unhandled promise rejection as described in [core js docs](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#unhandled-rejection-tracking)

More specifically, when debugging with Chrome, and opening the console, Promise.reject() does not yield a console.error()

Any ideas?

Also - I'm not sure why is react-native pollyfilling the Promise while it should be available on JavascriptCore as well on Chrome + Webkit executors.

Answer (score 1):

[react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/package.json#L104) is using [this](https://github.com/then/promise) Promises library and not core.js Promises.
This library does not support reporting unhandled exceptions

The reason for Polyfilling, at least currently with [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/70f94ef35b98811fb568c93494c6f9b7052d8fe5/library/modules/es6.promise.js#L45) and Chrome is related to this [V8 bug](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4162)

Comment: Note that this has now changed. this/Promises just added support for reporting unhandled exceptions, and react-native has added it too. Cf. https://github.com/then/promise/pull/116, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b0640946873945ee95d2cab8f549c915dbfffd70